# Django compare queryset from different databases

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I need to compare 2 querysets from the same model from 2 different databases.

I expect the difference between them. In this case, I grab only one column (charfield), from two databases and want to compare this "list", i.e. it would be great to work with sets and difference methods of sets.

But I can't simple subtract querysets, also set(queryset) and list(querysets) -- this give me nothing (not an error), i.e.

> diff_set = set(articles1) - set(articles2)

I switched db's on the fly, make 2 querysets and try to compare them (filter, or exclude)

```
articles1 = list(Smdocuments.objects.using('tmp1').only('id').filter(doctype__exact='CQ'))

# right connection
connections.databases['tmp2']['HOST'] = db2.host
connections.databases['tmp2']['NAME'] = db2.name
articles2 = list(Smdocuments.objects.using('tmp2').only('id').filter(doctype__exact='CQ'))

# okay to chain Smdocuments objects, gives all the entries
all = list(chain(articles1, articles2))

# got nothing, even len(diff_set) is none
diff_set = set(articles1) - set(articles2)

# this one raise error Subqueries aren't allowed across different databases.
articles_exclude = Smdocuments.objects.using('tmp1').only('id').filter(doctype__exact='CQ')
len(articles1)
diff_ex = Smdocuments.objects.using('tmp2').only('id').filter(doctype__exact='CQ').exclude(id__in=articles_exclude)
len(diff_ex)
```

diff_ex raise an error

> Subqueries aren't allowed across different databases. Force the inner
>   query to be evaluated using `list(inner_query)`.

So, "Model objects" not so easy to manipulate, and querysets between difference databases as well.

I see, thats not a good db scheme, but it's another application with distributed db, and I need to compare them.

It's would be enough to compare by one column, but probably compare full queryset will work for future.
Or, should I convert queryset to list and compare raw data?

Comment: Please post the actual outputs of your code (no one is going to setup a full django project just to test it) AND the expected outputs.

Comment: Updated the post, set(articles1) - set(articles2) got me nothing, but no error
Queryset method difference() also doesn't work with different db

Comment: This still doesn't explain what you expect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is really unclear about what you actually expect, but here are a couple hints anyway:

First, model instances (assuming they are instances of the same model of course) compare on their primary key value, which is also used as hash for dicts and sets, so if you want to compare the underlying database records you should not work on model instances but on the raw db values as lists of tuples or dicts. You can get those using (resp.) [`Queryset.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) or [`Queryset.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values) - not forgetting to `list()` them so you really get a `list` and not a `queryset`.

Which brings us to the second important point: while presenting themselves as list-likes (in that they support `len()`, iteration, subscripting and - with some restrictions - slicing), `Querysets` are NOT `lists`. You can't compare two querysets (well you can but they compare on identity, which means that two querysets will only be equal if they are actually the very same object), and, more important, using a queryset as an argument to a 'field__in=' lookup will result in a SQL subquery where passing a proper list results in a plain 'field IN (...)' where clause. This explains the error you get with the `exclude(...)` approach.

To make a long story short, if you want to effectively compare database rows, you want:

```
# the fields you want to compate records on
fields = 'field1', 'field2', 'fieldN'
rows1 =  list(YouModel.objects.using('tmp1').filter(...).values_list(*fields))
rows2 = list(YouModel.objects.using('tmp2').filter(...).values_list(*fields))

# now you have two lists of tuples so you can apply ordinary python comparisons / set operations etc
print rows1 == rows2
print set(rows1) - set(rows2)
# etc
```

Comment: Thank you, that should be exactly what I want. But, in my code that doesn't work. I'll check everything once again in console.

Comment: That's it!
And here is where I've stucked

.only() and .value_list() return different objects
for .value_list()
`[('0000000001',), ...`

and for .only()
`[<Smdocuments: 0000000001>, ...`

Comment: `Queryset.only()` returns models instance with "only" the specified fields filled from the db, where `Queryset.values_list()` returns raw data as tuples, indeed. All this is documented FWIW...